# SignOutAsync Make my User.Identity.IsAuthenticated still true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

when  i try to SignOut form my application which i authorized with gmail 
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still always true
this is my  code  for

```
public  IActionResult LogOff()
{
    HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/Index/" },
        "Google");
}
```

my startup code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
        options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Log/Outh/";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Log/LogOff/";
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Logging:GoogleCredintial:ClientID"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Logging:GoogleCredintial:ClientSecret"];
            options.CallbackPath = "/Log/Outh";
        });

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to `await` the `SignOutAsync`?

Comment: that is not the issue am  trying with await  too @mjwills

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The other answers on this subject are ancient and don't deal with `.net-core`.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't support third party sign-out.  Your not going to be able to sign-out a user out of their Google account only your own system.  Users will need to go to google and sign-out there.

The only way i have found to do it would be to delete the cookie

```
// Force delete the authentication cookie(s) we created when user signed in
if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.MyCookie"] != null)
   {
    var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.StartsWith("AspNetCore.MyCookie"));
    foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
       {
        Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
       }
    }
```

Comment: The only way i have found around it is deleting the cookie

Comment: not working for me still user after logoff User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true